# Why can't the VMs in my pen-testing lab ping each other?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have setup Kali Linux and Windows XP in Virtual Box.

My first problem is, these two systems are not being able to ping each other.

Second is, they are not being able to connect to the Internet (although, I don't know whether pen-testing labs should be allowed to use Internet or not.).

The network configurations looks like the following:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a networking question, not an InfoSec question - voting to migrate

Comment: I was going to say the problem is using "Host-Only", but the [VirtualBox User Guide](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html) seems to indicate VMs should be able to talk to each other *and* the host in this mode. They will not be able to get out to the Internet though. In any case, I usually prefer NAT or Bridged for Internet-enabled VMs and Internal for isolated VMs. I haven't really played with Host-only much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly expand the advanced options and change promiscuous mode to allow all so you will be able to pass the traffic. 
Secondly you will need to set up manually IP address, subnet and the gateway for each machine.

In your Kali machine you can do it by opening terminal console:

vim /etc/network/interfaces

and in your XP machine go to your local area network properties and again you need to set up manually IP address, subnet and the gateway.

Host only configuration is isolated network and if you have not got much networking experience and you are setting up pentesting lab for the first time I recommend you to use NAT configuration.